# webflux infinit stream per request

Tags: reactive-programming, server-sent-events, spring-webflux

I've been recently working on reactive programming to do a server sent events app and I have a use case I don't know if it could be done using webflux spring boot.
I have to do a stream of values per request so i've created my endpoint like this :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Long> Invoke() {
    return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(()-> 1)).interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
}
```

The problem now is that the endpoint "/subscribe" create each time it's called a Thread and I am not able to handle the large set of requests.
Note: The stream depends on the sender (Different stream per user)  , so implementing a hard stream could not be the right solution as I know.

Comment: Have you tried to return `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))`?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is that the above code cannot handle a large number of request because it creates a thread per request? Well, `interval` runs on a `Schedulers.parallel()` scheduler so maybe there are no enough threads in the pool. But I'm seeing another problem, `interval` generates another flux, so the values from `Flux.fromStream` are not returned. Maybe you shouldn't use `interval`.

Comment: Hello there , I am implementing this :     @GetMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Long> InvokeEvents() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    }, and unable to handle more then 7 requests ?? please check the screenshot here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NFjST3VVjZ2P13-_CqKYXh62FltpDv2t

Comment: Oh, I see. I was able to reproduce it using Chrome. Yes, the maximum number of tabs I can open is 7, the 8th didn't start until I closed one of the others. However, using Firefox I can open more than 7 (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bps1ef6kl83seiw/demo.mp4?dl=0), so probably it's just a Chrome limitation (it also worked with cURL, I opened like 10 tabs executing `curl --insecure https://localhost:8443/subscribe`).

Comment: I am facing the same problem using FireFox and curl , please get a look to the screenshots : https://drive.google.com/open?id=16zwGex87ke_W-4CpKf-uw8Kys94d9NdM https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NFjST3VVjZ2P13-_CqKYXh62FltpDv2t my app is only able to server a few requests at once

Comment: Are you testing with the code you posted? Because it works for me, I don't know what could be the problem, sorry I cannot help.